# XML interfering with javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg

This is a simplified version of the project I am working on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var bridge;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","MarketSpreadsheet.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 


    bridge = "xml data goes in here";

</script>


<svg height="300" width="300">
    <text id="thePopUp" x="150" y="150" font-size="30" fill="black" visibility="visible"></text>
</svg>

<script type="text/javascript">
thePopUp.textContent = bridge;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to create a dynamic svg element and for some reason, parsing the xml string directly into thePopUp.textContent wasn't working. My plan is to convert the xml data into a javascript variable matrix and use that to assign the text content. My issue is that the xml.http.send(); line is nullifying my variable assignment, making the output "undefined". I need that line to access my xml file, yet that line is keeping me from assigning the xml to a variable (or anything to a variable for that matter). Whats going on here?

Comment: Maybe you should first ask yourself why you’re trying to both support IE5 and use embedded SVG. Then, whether `xmlhttp.send()` is actually nullifying the following statement or whether `xmlhttp.responseXML` is actually `undefined` because the `Content-Type` on `MarketSpreadsheet.xml` is wrong, or whether the request didn’t succeed. And then whether it makes sense to put an XML DOM inside the `textContent` of an SVG `<text>` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
SAMPLE XML 
<exam courseName="MS Word" methodTxt="WRITE THE CORRECT OPTION IN ANSWER FIELD" exam_no="1" blankFeedback="Please write your answer">
    <item>
        <question><![CDATA[What is new in MS Word 2010?What is new in MS Word 2010?What is new in MS Word 2010?What is new in MS Word 2010?What is new in MS Word 2010?What is new in MS Word 2010?What is new in MS Word 2010?tapash]]></question>
        <acceptable_option this_question_marks="2">
            <option marks="2"><![CDATA[Tabs]]></option>
            <option marks=".4"><![CDATA[Buttons]]></option>
            <option marks=".4"><![CDATA[Check boxes]]></option>
            <option marks=".4"><![CDATA[Dialog boxes]]></option>
        </acceptable_option>
    </item>
    <item>
        <question><![CDATA[The Ribbon is divided into]]></question>
        <acceptable_option this_question_marks="2">
            <option marks="2"><![CDATA[Tabs]]></option>
        </acceptable_option>
    </item>
</exam>

AND JAVASCRIPT IS 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","xml/fill_in_the_blank.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;


    myXMLDoc=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('item');
    totalQuestion = myXMLDoc.length;
```

$("#thePopUp").text(totalQuestion)

BUT YOU NEED TO USE JQUERY AND "WEB SERVER OR SOMETHING LIKE WAMP"